# Single concurrent user access per page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache

In my system, I have specific pages for each user individually.
These pages are public but with a custom URL, and not meant to be shared, so each user has its own URL, i.e:
https://website.com/userID-456/name-surname

I need to prevent more than one concurrent user on the page.
If someone is on the page, and someone access the same page URL somewhere else, a popup must show something like "Your link was accessed on other device and this page will close" and redirect to some other URL.

My question is, how to work on this situation to constantly verify if the page was reached on some other device, browser, place?

I've seached for some solutions but nothing useful for my scenario.
The system is in PHP, I can use JS, Jquery, etc. I also work with Apache and MariaDB.

Any help or idea is welcome!

Edit: it doesn't need to check in real time, I can have some delay like some cronjob. Like every 1 or 2 minutes.

Comment: Generally this is solved by using some kind of session cookie and having people actually authenticate. A unique URL is not a secure solution. Also you can't tell if people are behind a single gateway using NAT to access your site. Generally, think of the way all the Internet hosts you normally use work; they don't do what you want to do.

Comment: @Pointy I aprecciate your comment. The ideas is not to be "private", the real scenario is we have some files (like audio) and some personal links were having like 400.000 visits. This costs resource and money to deliver. So we need a solution to prevent this "url share", but we can't have a login system for now.

Comment: Well a "login system" is clearly the way to deal with the problem. I don't know why you "can't have" such a thing, but it's the correct solution.

Comment: @Pointy I totally agree with you, but it's a clients demand. User get a link on e-mail and should just click and get to the page. I suggested some other solutions, but this is what they want for now. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Is the problem that the link is easily guessable, or that the recipient is sharing the link with others? I.e., can you just use a URL with a UUID instead of the user name? Can you have the link expire after a certain amount of time?

Comment: @AlexHowansky The problem is the sharing. Links are composed by ID and slug with real user names, so not easily guessable. We track the views and we remove manually big sharers, but with almost 250K users, it becomes hard to monitore all that. We can handle some little share, but one user per link is what they need. We have on the table a solution with limited accesses per day, no matter from where, but not approved yet.

Comment: Surely if the user is sharing the link of their own volition rather than others guessing it, then that's their problem rather than yours. If they shared it, why does it then matter if they don't have exclusive access to it? Not sure I quite understand the motivation for the requirement. Do your clients fully understand it? Sometimes customers ask for very odd things and occasionally our job is to let them down gently rather than code something you know makes no sense.

Comment: @ADyson Our problem with the sharing is the cost. Since we have some media files, caching/transfering 1 audio file is way different than 400.000.

Comment: Then maybe the restriction should actually be on the media files rather than the landing page which lists them? Otherwise people could just share the media links directly instead.

Comment: Even then, without identity management it will be very difficult to truly prevent concurrent streams / downloads I think - remember the web is essentially stateless for one thing, so what's your definition of concurrent? e.g. If I download a file 0.5 seconds after someone else downloaded the same one, is that ok? And how do you define "someone else"? Remember a single IP can be shared by hundreds of people in some cases, and equally a single individual could legitimately have multiple IPs. Even massive corps like Netflix et al. have not fully solved these kinds of issues.

Comment: "Well Mr. Client, we can use authentication to control access to the resources being hosted on our infrastructure, or we can send you a bill for all the unauthorized transfers incurred by your stated requirements."

Answer (score 1):

To allow only one person at a time to access a webpage, without authentication and without cookies, you can use this simple workaround. This workaround is not good for production, but it doesn't seem like you're looking for a perfect answer. You want this to work, and I will help you.

An empty text file called "Locked.txt" will control this procedure.

When the user visits the page, it checks if Locked.txt exists. If it exists and is younger than a specified time, it displays an error message saying they are unable to view at this time. If Locked.txt does not exist, or it has been locked for longer than a certain time, it permits the user access to the page and then locks it.

```
function showPage($fileName = null)
{
   file_exists($fileName) ? unlink($fileName) : '';
   file_put_contents($fileName, "");
   // Show contents of page to user.
}  

$file = "Locked.txt";
if (file_exists($file))
{
  if (time()-filemtime($filename) > 2 * 3600) 
  {
    // Locked for more than 2 hours
    showPage($file);
  } else {
    // file younger than 2 hours
    echo "Oops!...";
  }
} else {
// Locked file doesn't exist at all, first implementation.
showPage($file);
}
```